# How to ignore certain files in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a file in `templates` directory called `ingress.yaml.ignore` that I'd like to preserve for informative reasons. How can I exclude it, so it won't be picked during installation?

Answer (score 2):

any option to ignore file 'on the fly' ?

I'd like sth similar to that

generate helm template --ignore templates/secrets.yaml

So I could print it safely in a pipeline

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `*.ignore` pattern to `.helmignore` file. Check Helm's [.helmignore](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/helm_ignore_file/) docs for more details.